# If, else statement returns both in tf.function

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, if-statement

I want to make a function which can handle both floats and vectors as input using Tensorflow in Python. I defined the following function:

```
def g(t):
    if tf.rank(t) == 0:
        print('Rank=0')
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.exp(t))
    else:
        print('Rank=higher')
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.exp(t),1)
```

However, I want to call the function in another tf.function. As a test I made the following function :

```
@tf.function
def Test(t):
    return g(t)
```

Calling g(0.5) gives

```
Rank=0
Out[218]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.7182817>
```

Calling Test(0.5) gives:

```
rank=0
rank=higher
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [219] in <cell line: 1>
    Test(0.5)

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py:153 in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filegb02ol08.py:12 in tf__Test
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(gn), (ag__.ld(t),), None, fscope)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filegnzfdu42.py:37 in tf__gn
    ag__.if_stmt(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(int), (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).rank, (ag__.ld(t),), None, fscope),), None, fscope) == 0, if_body, else_body, get_state, set_state, ('do_return', 'retval_'), 2)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filegnzfdu42.py:33 in else_body
    retval_ = ag__.ld(V0) + ag__.ld(labda) * ag__.ld(theta) * ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).math.reduce_sum, (ag__.ld(c) / ag__.ld(gamma) * (1 - ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).math.exp, (-ag__.ld(gamma) * ag__.ld(t),), None, fscope)), 1), None, fscope)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\jgrou\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11872\3135092574.py", line 11, in Test  *
        return gn(t)
    File "C:\Users\jgrou\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11872\3135092574.py", line 7, in gn  *
        return V0 + labda * theta * tf.math.reduce_sum(c / gamma * (1 - tf.math.exp(-gamma * t)),1)

    ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 1 for input with 1 dimensions. for '{{node cond/Sum}} = Sum[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, keep_dims=false](cond/mul_1, cond/Sum/reduction_indices)' with input shapes: [1], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1>.
```

Why do both arguments of the if-else statement get called in the tf.function? And how can I make the function g work inside a tf.function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like someone brought this behavior up in a fairly recent [Github Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/54790). Highlighting the response from one of the Tensorflow developers before closing the issue:

```
The cause of this problem is due to the behavior of condition tracing in TensorFlow: the same input is applied to both true and false sides for graph tracing, when the condition is based on a non-static value (i.e. tf.rank(v) == 2).
```

There are two viable solutions.

## Use Constant Value

If you use `tf.get_static_value` (details [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_static_value)) to return the constant value of the 0-D Tensor returned by `tf.rank`, it prevents the condition tracing, as it evaluates the Tensor (converts it to an int, float, numpy array, etc. depending on the shape and type).

```py
def g(t):
    if tf.get_static_value(tf.rank(t)) == 0:
        print('Rank=0')
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.exp(t))
    else:
        print('Rank=higher')
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.exp(t), 1)
```

This returns the expected results:

```
Rank=0
tf.Tensor(1.6487212, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Rank=0
tf.Tensor(1.6487212, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

## Direct Shape Evaluation

Rather than using `tf.rank`, evaluate the shape directly, which also requires converting any non-Tensor inputs to a Tensor:

```
def g(t):
    if not isinstance(t, tf.Tensor):
        t = tf.convert_to_tensor(t)
    if t.shape.ndims == 0:
        print('Rank=0')
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.exp(t))
    else:
        print('Rank=higher')
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.exp(t), 1)
```

This implementation also yields the expected results:

```
Rank=0
tf.Tensor(1.6487212, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Rank=0
tf.Tensor(1.6487212, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```